# Networkx: Importing graph with node values and edges information

Tags: networkx

I am generating random Geometric graph using networkx. I am exporting all the node and edges information into file. 
I want to generate the same graph by importing all the node and edges information from file.

Code to export the node values and edge information.

```
G=nx.random_geometric_graph(10,0.5) 
filename = "ipRandomGrid.txt" 
fh=open(filename,'wb') 
nx.write_adjlist(G, fh) 
nx.draw(G) 
plt.show()
```

I am trying to export it with below code and trying to change the color of some nodes. But it is generating different graph.

```
filename = "ipRandomGrid.txt" 
fh=open(filename, 'rb') 
G=nx.Graph() 
G=nx.read_adjlist("ipRandomGrid.txt") 
pos=nx.random_layout(G) 
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=['1','2'],node_color='b') 
nx.draw(G) 
plt.show()
```

How to generate the same graph with few changes in color of some nodes?

Comment: What do you mean by a "different graph"? Please use code that shows the difference you have in mind, rather than an arbitrary assortment of graph manipulations. In particular, different random layouts of a graph won't show a meaningful difference.

Comment: It is generating 2 extra nodes 1 and 2 at random location in the graph. The idea is to have the same graph having the same position with few changes in node colors.

Comment: Graphs don't have positions. You're talking about the layout, then?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for same layout.

Comment: I've answered based on what I'm guessing you mean. Please edit your question to make it better reflect what you want -- it's hard to tell from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem you're having correctly, the trouble is here:

```
pos=nx.random_layout(G) 
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=['1','2'],node_color='b') 
nx.draw(G)
```

You create a random layout of the graph in the first line, and use it to draw nodes `'1'` and `'2'` in the second line. You then draw the graph again in the third line without specifying the positions, which uses a spring model to position the nodes.

Your graph has no extra nodes, you've just drawn two of them in two different positions. If you want to consistently draw a graph the same way, you need to consistently use the `pos` you calculated. If you want it to be the same after storing and reloading, then save `pos` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to store node position data for your case might be using Python pickles.  NetworkX has a write_gpickle() function that will do this for you.  Note that the positions are already available as node attributes when you generate a random geometric graph so you probably want to use those when drawing.  Here is an example of how to generate, save, load, and draw the same graph.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G=nx.random_geometric_graph(10,0.5)

In [3]: pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')

In [4]: nx.draw(G,pos)

In [5]: nx.write_gpickle(G,'rgg.gpl')

In [6]: H=nx.read_gpickle('rgg.gpl')

In [7]: pos = nx.get_node_attributes(H,'pos')

In [8]: nx.draw(H,pos)
```